# Master details hamburger icon not showing in xamarin latest pre release 5.0.0.1791

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which uses a master Details page. I updated the xamarin.forms package to  `Latest 5.0.0.1791-pre5`. The reason why I updated to latest pre release was I want to provide `DynamicResource` to LinearGradientBrush which have issues on `Latest Stable 4.8`.

Now after updating to latest pre release, the hamburger icon of master details page disappeared. When I downgraded to latest stable the icon shows. Is it only occurring to me or is this a bug of latest package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After XF 5.0 ,`MasterDetailPage` has been renamed to **FlyoutPage**. This is a deprecation, so your app will work as before. To adopt this change, we recommend you rename **MasterDetailPage** in your projects to **FlyoutPage**. Check [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0-pre4#masterdetailpage-renamed) .

In your case ,as a workaround you could set a custom icon for the Master page .

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MasterDetailPageMaster  IconImageSource="test.png" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

And put the icon to iOS **project ->Assets** and **Android Resource -> drawable** .